# Flutter GetX complex Navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

**EDIT:**

The problem is regarding navigation, Im using GetX for navigation, and the problem is that using Get.back() isn't refreshing the state of the page that I want to get back to, so I need to use Get.toNamed.

This `onPressed` is used on my back button (on **`"screen2"`**)

I can go to **`"screen2"`** page from `"home"`, `"screen1"` and `"screen3"`.

`"home"` and`"screen1"` are parent screens to **`"screen2"`** (is you can say it like that),
but `"screen3"` is only accessed **from `"screen2"`**.

Now, when I return to **`"screen2"`** from `"screen3"`, GetX saves the previous route of `"screen3"`

and when I press the back button(on **`"screen2"`**) , it should either go to `"home"` or `"screen1"`, depends on from **where I opened `"screen2"`**

It's pretty simple, but it's hard to explain in a simple way

[image]

**EDIT**: The upper part was easy, but now, there is the final boss:
I believe that those below are all the routes.

The problem is probably around **`about path`** screen, cause it is the part where the most data goes through.

```
Home -> about mountain,
Home -> about path,
Home -> about poi,
Home -> about mountain -> about path 
Home -> about mountain -> about path -> about poi
Home -> mountains screen -> about mountain -> about path
Home -> mountains screen -> about mountain -> about path -> about poi
Home -> paths screen -> about path
Home -> paths screen -> about path -> about poi
```

All possible routes are listed above
[image]

**`"screen2"`** is the same as **`"ABOUT MOUNTAIN"`**

I don't know if there is a better way of doing this other that using a bunch of conditionals.

[image]
(this is clearly wrong, there must be a more elegant approach)

Comment: What you are trying to do with this code please explain more

Comment: add more detail please

Comment: Now I can understand your question. Have you got the solution.

Comment: we'll see, will try to save the previous route on build and save it locally and then using that previous route to go back to the right screen and refreshing the state at the same time

Comment: if you could refresh the state of the previous screen in Get.back(), this wouldn't be a problem

Comment: Explain a bit about your boss.

Answer (score 1):

define help var in onpressed function.try this:

```
    onPressed: () {
final String help='';
                          if (Get.previousRoute == AppRoutes.home) {
                            help = Get.previousRoute.toString();
                            Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.home);
                          } else if(Get.previousRoute == AppRoutes.screen2){
                            String help = Get.previousRoute.toString();
                            Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.screen2);
                          } else{
                            Get.toNamed(help);  //can't use variable help here
                          }
                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding argument `returnUrl` which contains `home` or `Screen1` to your url to `screen2` and pass the same argument to `Screen3`.

Get the argument `returnUrl` using

```dart
Get.arguments['returnUrl'];
```

Use the argument value to route from `screen2` to home/screen1

Comment: Thats great, Then upvote and accept my answer. Mark question as [Closed]

Comment: now I'll have to go one level deeper so wish me luck